# How to show colored notification for media in Android Oreo?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications, android-music-player

[image]

As you already know that **Android Oreo** introduced the new design for **media controls**, rather than selecting a singular color for the **notification based on the app's color**, media playback notifications can instead **draw colors out of the album artwork**. Android then uses those colors to make a notification that blends the artwork into the notification while making the notification itself pop in your **notification shade**.

May I know how we can do this ?

Comment: please help me for the same CHECK THE LINK https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633202/how-to-set-mediaplayer-notification-with-mediasession-and-notificationcompat-med

Answer (score 3):

This is MediaStyle for Notification. You need to set MediaStyle and media session tokon and thats it. For example:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);

//building some actions...

builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2)
                        .setShowCancelButton(true)
                        .setMediaSession(mediaSessionCompat.getSessionToken()))
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_TRANSPORT)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setShowWhen(false)
                .setContentTitle("Title Name")
                .setContentText("Content text")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pause)
                .setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setLargeIcon(icon);
```

You can find tutorial here:
[Tutorial](https://medium.com/google-developers/migrating-mediastyle-notifications-to-support-android-o-29c7edeca9b7)

Comment: what is mediaSessionCompat.getSessionToken() I mean How to set this and how to start this as foreground service

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

To fill with solid colour:

```
.setColorized(boolean colorize)
```

Set whether this notification should be colorized.

-A media template lets the user control media currently playing from an app.

The collapsed view displays up to three actions, and the large icon can show a related image, such as an album cover.

The expanded view displays up to five actions with a larger image, or six actions if no image is displayed. Colors from provided images automatically color the notification's background and other elements.
(https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-templates)

-Media notifications will automatically get colorized based on the album art.
The Palette API takes the album art, extracts some colors, and applies it to the media player notification.

Comment: Apparently media notifications will automatically get colorized based on the album art.
The Palette API takes the album art, extracts some colors, and applies it to the media player notification.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html          https://developer.android.com/training/material/palette-colors.html

Comment: But how the media control images are changing ?